# Problems with "Team Foundation Server is not your current Source Control plug-in" when I try to start a new project in VS2017

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am new to Visual Studio 2017 and VSTS.
From my VSTS page I choose to create a new application and clone it in Visual Studio.
When I do this it launches Visual Studio. But then I get these error messages. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: The Source Control Explorer is used for TFVC not Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the message again. It seems a bug for VSTS to clone in VS2017 directly by click **Clone in Visual Studio** button. I feedback the issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/45956/vs2017-shows-team-foundation-server-is-not-your-cu.html), you can vote and follow up.

But actually this message has no effect for you to continue work on the working copy because it actually cloned successfully. You can go ahead to add/commit/push changes to VSTS.

Besides, there has another way to clone git repo byVS2017. Team explorer -> manage connection -> manage connection -> choose the new created git repo -> clone. And you can refer [clone an existing git repo](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/clone).

Comment: It's turned out that it's not bug, this window just for TFVC: **your source control provider is changed to Git in VS. However, because you have the Source Control Explorer window open (which is for TFVC), that window displays that message so you know why that it is blank**. So just ignore this message when you clone git repo by clone in visual studio button.

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution, that worked for me:

1. Click on "Team Foundation Server is not you ..." link
2. In the Plug-in Selection Select "None" as your Current source control plug-in and click "OK"
3. Click on "Source Control Explorer again
4. Click on "Team Foundation Server is not your ..." link again
5. Now select "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" and click "OK"

Comment: Hot. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome. But I also had to click the Refresh button within Source Control Explorer

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue when opening an already created project into a TSVC Source Control connection. The message was related because the project itself contained the git default files and folders i.e. .git, .ignore etc. Once these files were removed from the project folder I was able to succesfully open the project in VS 2017. You can them go to the project folder and observe the creation of $vs folder which is the mark for tsvc imported project.